# Microsoft graph onenote content api returning contents by replacing <br> with [obj] character

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I am creating a OneNote page with [OneNote api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/section-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0) with some HTML which has a html line break(br) character. Following a simple trimmed version of the HTML used to create the one note page.

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div >        
            Hello
            <br/>
            World
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After creating I can verify that the content looks expected in OneNote client both online and native.

[image]

When I try getting the page content using grpah api [content endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-get?view=graph-rest-1.0). I get the following response

```
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
    <div data-id="_default" style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:120px;width:624px">
        <p style="margin-top:5.5pt;margin-bottom:5.5pt">Hello ￼World </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Between Hello and World there is a special character [[OBJ]](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm). Why the br is replaced with [OBJ] character. Are there other things also which are replaced with this character during getting the page content?